# how to speed up mysql query using information_schema

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find tables that do not have a specified column name:

```
select t.table_name
from information_schema.tables as t
  left join information_schema.columns as c
    on t.table_name=c.table_name
      and c.column_name='some_name'
where c.column_name is null
```

and this is very, very slow. is there any way to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using InnoDB tables, set the global variable: innodb_stats_on_metadata to 0.  By default, the InnoDB engine will update statistics when schema information is accessed for its tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.table_name
FROM information_schema.table as t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns c 
                  WHERE c.table_name = t.table_name)
```

Comment: @akonsu: Have you tried bobwienholt's answer - see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/ for why this is slow and how changing this setting can help.